# Como obtengo un fragmento de un string con python y lo almaceno en una variable?

Tags: python, string, split

actualmente he estado intentando obtener un fragmento de un string con Python, justo los números después de la palabra (SECUENCIA:), he intentado con split, pero la verdad no entiendo split muy bien y no obtengo el resultado que quiero, si me recomiendan una documentación en español, de antemano gracias.

Ejemplo:

x = "COPIA CLIENTE B LOTE:113 REF:10 NRO.CTA:*********8078 'C' FECHA:24/01/2024 13:07:27 APROB:00 NA:DEBITO SECUENCIA:5200 CAJMONTO BS.444,00"

Necesito obtener el número 5200.

Comment: Nosotros no damos guias ni recomendaciones de recursos externos. Sin embargo, existen muchos tutoriales de split y la documentación de Python se encuentra en español

Comment: Hola Richard, bienvenido a [es.so]. Pedir recomendaciones de recursos externos esta fuera de los lineamientos del sitio, en gran parte porque las respuestas son siempre subjetivas y basadas en opiniones personales. No obstante,  lo que si puedes hacer es [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/612225/edit) y agregar el código que has intentado pidiendo ayuda para solventar el problema en vez de recomendaciones, asi podemos darte  soluciones y explicaciones para tu caso concreto. Te recomiendo mirarte [tour] y [ask] para conocer un poco como funciona el sitio. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

x = "COPIA CLIENTE B LOTE:113 REF:10 NRO.CTA:*********8078 'C' FECHA:24/01/2024 13:07:27 APROB:00 NA:DEBITO SECUENCIA:5200 CAJMONTO BS.444,00"

match = re.search(r"SECUENCIA:(\d+)", x)

if match:
    resultado = match.group(1)
    print(resultado)
else:
    print("No se encontró ninguna coincidencia.")
```

En este código, la expresión regular SECUENCIA:(\d+) busca la cadena "SECUENCIA:" seguida de uno o más dígitos (\d+). El uso de paréntesis indica que queremos capturar esos dígitos como un grupo. Luego, match.group(1) devuelve el contenido del primer grupo capturado, que en este caso sería el número que estás buscando.

Comment: Wao muchas gracias funciono a la perfección, voy a buscar más documentación de "re", porque la verdad estaba trancado en esto y tuve que recurrir a estos foros. Excelente aporte !

Comment: Me alegra saber que te sirvió, saludos y suerte.